# Remove padding around styled component input

Tags: css, styled-components

**GOAL:** Remove invisible padding around the color swatch so that the color fills the entire container.

I'm trying to fill the entire wrapper with the selected color.
However, there seems to be invisible padding on the input field:

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./styles.css";

const Container = styled.span`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

  input[type="color"] {
    border: 1px solid var(--main-grey);
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Poppins;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
    margin:
    &::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
      margin:-100px;
      padding: 0px;
   
      border: none;
      overflow: none;
    }
    &::-webkit-color-swatch {
      padding: 18px;
      border:none;
      border-radius: 8px;

      margin: 0px;
      
    }
  }

  input[type="text"] {
    border: 1px solid var(--main-grey);
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Poppins;
  }
`;

const ColorPicker = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="color__pickerWrapper">
        <input type="color" {...props} />
        <input type="text" {...props} />
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default function Color() {
  const [state, updateState] = useState("#FFFFFF");

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    updateState(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ColorPicker onChange={handleInput} value={state} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think there is some invisible padding around the input. However, I tried 0px margin and 0px padding and it still didn't solve the problem. Perhaps it is an issue with styled components?

Comment: It's not the issue with styled components. You already set ` padding: 0;` and `border: 0` so I guess you can't remove those space from background. However you can instead remove border of input color to make it look it takes the full width and height. https://codesandbox.io/s/test-anything-dj1pc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: hey man, i don't think your codesandbox is rendering correctly? Everything is spaced unevenlyly

Comment: It's working fine for me. I just remove `border` from color input and remove `padding: 18px;` inside `&::-webkit-color-swatch` and add `width: 30px` and `height: 30px`. I didn't change a lot of codes.

Answer (score -1):

It's not an elegant solution and may bring several problems in other parts that you desire the margins to appear.

Still, if you want to brute forcefully remove them go to your index.html file, within the public folder and add the code below after your head ends , and before your body starts :

```html
  <style>
    * {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This will remove padding and margin on literally every element in your page unless you also use !important to override more specific needs. Highly recommend avoiding doing this!

Comment: Yes, buddy! That's exactly what I've said. If you have a better suggestion that actually works, please post. It will be super helpful for everyone. Just criticizing won't do anything for the community.